# Using Darknet YOLOv4 in python to detect objects from an image opens and closes the image and doesn't print detected objects

Tags: python, opencv, darknet, yolov4

So I'm using the Darknet Framework with YoloV4.
This is my yolo_image.py code:

```
import darknet
import cv2

# darknet helper function to run detection on image


def darknet_helper(img, width, height):
    darknet_image = darknet.make_image(width, height, 3)
    img_rgb = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
    img_resized = cv2.resize(img_rgb, (width, height),
                             interpolation=cv2.INTER_LINEAR)
    # get image ratios to convert bounding boxes to proper size
    img_height, img_width, _ = img.shape
    width_ratio = img_width / width
    height_ratio = img_height / height
    #    run model on darknet style image to get detections
    darknet.copy_image_from_bytes(darknet_image, img_resized.tobytes())
    detections = darknet.detect_image(network, class_names, darknet_image)
    darknet.free_image(darknet_image)
    return detections, width_ratio, height_ratio


if __name__ == "__main__":
    # network, class_names, class_colors = darknet.load_network("cfg/yolov4.cfg",
    #                                                           "cfg/coco.data",
    #                                                           "yolov4.weights")
    network, class_names, class_colors = darknet.load_network("build/darknet/x64/cfg/yolov4.cfg",
                                                              "build/darknet/x64/cfg/coco.data",
                                                              "build/darknet/x64/yolov4.weights")
    width = darknet.network_width(network)
    height = darknet.network_height(network)
    image = cv2.imread("build/darknet/x64/data/person.jpg")
    # image = cv2.imread("data/person.jpg")
    detections, width_ratio, height_ratio = darknet_helper(image, width, height)

    for label, confidence, bbox in detections:
        left, top, right, bottom = darknet.bbox2points(bbox)
        left, top, right, bottom = int(left * width_ratio), int(top * height_ratio), int(right * width_ratio), int(
            bottom * height_ratio)
        cv2.rectangle(image, (left, top), (right, bottom), class_colors[label], 2)
        cv2.putText(image, "{} [{:.2f}]".format(label, float(confidence)),
                    (left, top - 5), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.5,
                    class_colors[label], 2)
    cv2.imshow('ex', image)
```

When I use the command python build/darknet/x64/yolo_image.py(my python executable is in the root folder), I get this output:

```
 Try to load cfg: build/darknet/x64/cfg/yolov4.cfg, weights: build/darknet/x64/yolov4.weights, clear = 0
 0 : compute_capability = 750, cudnn_half = 1, GPU: GeForce GTX 1660 Ti
net.optimized_memory = 0
mini_batch = 1, batch = 8, time_steps = 1, train = 0
   layer   filters  size/strd(dil)      input                output
   0 Create CUDA-stream - 0
 Create cudnn-handle 0
conv     32       3 x 3/ 1    608 x 608 x   3 ->  608 x 608 x  32 0.639 BF
   1 conv     64       3 x 3/ 2    608 x 608 x  32 ->  304 x 304 x  64 3.407 BF
   2 conv     64       1 x 1/ 1    304 x 304 x  64 ->  304 x 304 x  64 0.757 BF
   3 route  1                                      ->  304 x 304 x  64
   4 conv     64       1 x 1/ 1    304 x 304 x  64 ->  304 x 304 x  64 0.757 BF
   5 conv     32       1 x 1/ 1    304 x 304 x  64 ->  304 x 304 x  32 0.379 BF
   6 conv     64       3 x 3/ 1    304 x 304 x  32 ->  304 x 304 x  64 3.407 BF
   7 Shortcut Layer: 4,  wt = 0, wn = 0, outputs: 304 x 304 x  64 0.006 BF
   8 conv     64       1 x 1/ 1    304 x 304 x  64 ->  304 x 304 x  64 0.757 BF
   9 route  8 2                                    ->  304 x 304 x 128
  10 conv     64       1 x 1/ 1    304 x 304 x 128 ->  304 x 304 x  64 1.514 BF
  11 conv    128       3 x 3/ 2    304 x 304 x  64 ->  152 x 152 x 128 3.407 BF
  12 conv     64       1 x 1/ 1    152 x 152 x 128 ->  152 x 152 x  64 0.379 BF
  13 route  11                                     ->  152 x 152 x 128
  14 conv     64       1 x 1/ 1    152 x 152 x 128 ->  152 x 152 x  64 0.379 BF
  15 conv     64       1 x 1/ 1    152 x 152 x  64 ->  152 x 152 x  64 0.189 BF
  16 conv     64       3 x 3/ 1    152 x 152 x  64 ->  152 x 152 x  64 1.703 BF
  17 Shortcut Layer: 14,  wt = 0, wn = 0, outputs: 152 x 152 x  64 0.001 BF
  18 conv     64       1 x 1/ 1    152 x 152 x  64 ->  152 x 152 x  64 0.189 BF
  19 conv     64       3 x 3/ 1    152 x 152 x  64 ->  152 x 152 x  64 1.703 BF
  20 Shortcut Layer: 17,  wt = 0, wn = 0, outputs: 152 x 152 x  64 0.001 BF
  21 conv     64       1 x 1/ 1    152 x 152 x  64 ->  152 x 152 x  64 0.189 BF
  22 route  21 12                                  ->  152 x 152 x 128
  23 conv    128       1 x 1/ 1    152 x 152 x 128 ->  152 x 152 x 128 0.757 BF
  24 conv    256       3 x 3/ 2    152 x 152 x 128 ->   76 x  76 x 256 3.407 BF
  25 conv    128       1 x 1/ 1     76 x  76 x 256 ->   76 x  76 x 128 0.379 BF
  26 route  24                                     ->   76 x  76 x 256
  27 conv    128       1 x 1/ 1     76 x  76 x 256 ->   76 x  76 x 128 0.379 BF
  28 conv    128       1 x 1/ 1     76 x  76 x 128 ->   76 x  76 x 128 0.189 BF
  29 conv    128       3 x 3/ 1     76 x  76 x 128 ->   76 x  76 x 128 1.703 BF
  30 Shortcut Layer: 27,  wt = 0, wn = 0, outputs:  76 x  76 x 128 0.001 BF
  31 conv    128       1 x 1/ 1     76 x  76 x 128 ->   76 x  76 x 128 0.189 BF
  32 conv    128       3 x 3/ 1     76 x  76 x 128 ->   76 x  76 x 128 1.703 BF
  33 Shortcut Layer: 30,  wt = 0, wn = 0, outputs:  76 x  76 x 128 0.001 BF
  34 conv    128       1 x 1/ 1     76 x  76 x 128 ->   76 x  76 x 128 0.189 BF
  35 conv    128       3 x 3/ 1     76 x  76 x 128 ->   76 x  76 x 128 1.703 BF
  36 Shortcut Layer: 33,  wt = 0, wn = 0, outputs:  76 x  76 x 128 0.001 BF
  37 conv    128       1 x 1/ 1     76 x  76 x 128 ->   76 x  76 x 128 0.189 BF
  38 conv    128       3 x 3/ 1     76 x  76 x 128 ->   76 x  76 x 128 1.703 BF
  39 Shortcut Layer: 36,  wt = 0, wn = 0, outputs:  76 x  76 x 128 0.001 BF
  40 conv    128       1 x 1/ 1     76 x  76 x 128 ->   76 x  76 x 128 0.189 BF
  41 conv    128       3 x 3/ 1     76 x  76 x 128 ->   76 x  76 x 128 1.703 BF
  42 Shortcut Layer: 39,  wt = 0, wn = 0, outputs:  76 x  76 x 128 0.001 BF
  43 conv    128       1 x 1/ 1     76 x  76 x 128 ->   76 x  76 x 128 0.189 BF
  44 conv    128       3 x 3/ 1     76 x  76 x 128 ->   76 x  76 x 128 1.703 BF
  45 Shortcut Layer: 42,  wt = 0, wn = 0, outputs:  76 x  76 x 128 0.001 BF
  46 conv    128       1 x 1/ 1     76 x  76 x 128 ->   76 x  76 x 128 0.189 BF
  47 conv    128       3 x 3/ 1     76 x  76 x 128 ->   76 x  76 x 128 1.703 BF
  48 Shortcut Layer: 45,  wt = 0, wn = 0, outputs:  76 x  76 x 128 0.001 BF
  49 conv    128       1 x 1/ 1     76 x  76 x 128 ->   76 x  76 x 128 0.189 BF
  50 conv    128       3 x 3/ 1     76 x  76 x 128 ->   76 x  76 x 128 1.703 BF
  51 Shortcut Layer: 48,  wt = 0, wn = 0, outputs:  76 x  76 x 128 0.001 BF
  52 conv    128       1 x 1/ 1     76 x  76 x 128 ->   76 x  76 x 128 0.189 BF
  53 route  52 25                                  ->   76 x  76 x 256
  54 conv    256       1 x 1/ 1     76 x  76 x 256 ->   76 x  76 x 256 0.757 BF
  55 conv    512       3 x 3/ 2     76 x  76 x 256 ->   38 x  38 x 512 3.407 BF
  56 conv    256       1 x 1/ 1     38 x  38 x 512 ->   38 x  38 x 256 0.379 BF
  57 route  55                                     ->   38 x  38 x 512
  58 conv    256       1 x 1/ 1     38 x  38 x 512 ->   38 x  38 x 256 0.379 BF
  59 conv    256       1 x 1/ 1     38 x  38 x 256 ->   38 x  38 x 256 0.189 BF
  60 conv    256       3 x 3/ 1     38 x  38 x 256 ->   38 x  38 x 256 1.703 BF
  61 Shortcut Layer: 58,  wt = 0, wn = 0, outputs:  38 x  38 x 256 0.000 BF
  62 conv    256       1 x 1/ 1     38 x  38 x 256 ->   38 x  38 x 256 0.189 BF
  63 conv    256       3 x 3/ 1     38 x  38 x 256 ->   38 x  38 x 256 1.703 BF
  64 Shortcut Layer: 61,  wt = 0, wn = 0, outputs:  38 x  38 x 256 0.000 BF
  65 conv    256       1 x 1/ 1     38 x  38 x 256 ->   38 x  38 x 256 0.189 BF
  66 conv    256       3 x 3/ 1     38 x  38 x 256 ->   38 x  38 x 256 1.703 BF
  67 Shortcut Layer: 64,  wt = 0, wn = 0, outputs:  38 x  38 x 256 0.000 BF
  68 conv    256       1 x 1/ 1     38 x  38 x 256 ->   38 x  38 x 256 0.189 BF
  69 conv    256       3 x 3/ 1     38 x  38 x 256 ->   38 x  38 x 256 1.703 BF
  70 Shortcut Layer: 67,  wt = 0, wn = 0, outputs:  38 x  38 x 256 0.000 BF
  71 conv    256       1 x 1/ 1     38 x  38 x 256 ->   38 x  38 x 256 0.189 BF
  72 conv    256       3 x 3/ 1     38 x  38 x 256 ->   38 x  38 x 256 1.703 BF
  73 Shortcut Layer: 70,  wt = 0, wn = 0, outputs:  38 x  38 x 256 0.000 BF
  74 conv    256       1 x 1/ 1     38 x  38 x 256 ->   38 x  38 x 256 0.189 BF
  75 conv    256       3 x 3/ 1     38 x  38 x 256 ->   38 x  38 x 256 1.703 BF
  76 Shortcut Layer: 73,  wt = 0, wn = 0, outputs:  38 x  38 x 256 0.000 BF
  77 conv    256       1 x 1/ 1     38 x  38 x 256 ->   38 x  38 x 256 0.189 BF
  78 conv    256       3 x 3/ 1     38 x  38 x 256 ->   38 x  38 x 256 1.703 BF
  79 Shortcut Layer: 76,  wt = 0, wn = 0, outputs:  38 x  38 x 256 0.000 BF
  80 conv    256       1 x 1/ 1     38 x  38 x 256 ->   38 x  38 x 256 0.189 BF
  81 conv    256       3 x 3/ 1     38 x  38 x 256 ->   38 x  38 x 256 1.703 BF
  82 Shortcut Layer: 79,  wt = 0, wn = 0, outputs:  38 x  38 x 256 0.000 BF
  83 conv    256       1 x 1/ 1     38 x  38 x 256 ->   38 x  38 x 256 0.189 BF
  84 route  83 56                                  ->   38 x  38 x 512
  85 conv    512       1 x 1/ 1     38 x  38 x 512 ->   38 x  38 x 512 0.757 BF
  86 conv   1024       3 x 3/ 2     38 x  38 x 512 ->   19 x  19 x1024 3.407 BF
  87 conv    512       1 x 1/ 1     19 x  19 x1024 ->   19 x  19 x 512 0.379 BF
  88 route  86                                     ->   19 x  19 x1024
  89 conv    512       1 x 1/ 1     19 x  19 x1024 ->   19 x  19 x 512 0.379 BF
  90 conv    512       1 x 1/ 1     19 x  19 x 512 ->   19 x  19 x 512 0.189 BF
  91 conv    512       3 x 3/ 1     19 x  19 x 512 ->   19 x  19 x 512 1.703 BF
  92 Shortcut Layer: 89,  wt = 0, wn = 0, outputs:  19 x  19 x 512 0.000 BF
  93 conv    512       1 x 1/ 1     19 x  19 x 512 ->   19 x  19 x 512 0.189 BF
  94 conv    512       3 x 3/ 1     19 x  19 x 512 ->   19 x  19 x 512 1.703 BF
  95 Shortcut Layer: 92,  wt = 0, wn = 0, outputs:  19 x  19 x 512 0.000 BF
  96 conv    512       1 x 1/ 1     19 x  19 x 512 ->   19 x  19 x 512 0.189 BF
  97 conv    512       3 x 3/ 1     19 x  19 x 512 ->   19 x  19 x 512 1.703 BF
  98 Shortcut Layer: 95,  wt = 0, wn = 0, outputs:  19 x  19 x 512 0.000 BF
  99 conv    512       1 x 1/ 1     19 x  19 x 512 ->   19 x  19 x 512 0.189 BF
 100 conv    512       3 x 3/ 1     19 x  19 x 512 ->   19 x  19 x 512 1.703 BF
 101 Shortcut Layer: 98,  wt = 0, wn = 0, outputs:  19 x  19 x 512 0.000 BF
 102 conv    512       1 x 1/ 1     19 x  19 x 512 ->   19 x  19 x 512 0.189 BF
 103 route  102 87                                 ->   19 x  19 x1024
 104 conv   1024       1 x 1/ 1     19 x  19 x1024 ->   19 x  19 x1024 0.757 BF
 105 conv    512       1 x 1/ 1     19 x  19 x1024 ->   19 x  19 x 512 0.379 BF
 106 conv   1024       3 x 3/ 1     19 x  19 x 512 ->   19 x  19 x1024 3.407 BF
 107 conv    512       1 x 1/ 1     19 x  19 x1024 ->   19 x  19 x 512 0.379 BF
 108 max                5x 5/ 1     19 x  19 x 512 ->   19 x  19 x 512 0.005 BF
 109 route  107                                            ->   19 x  19 x 512
 110 max                9x 9/ 1     19 x  19 x 512 ->   19 x  19 x 512 0.015 BF
 111 route  107                                            ->   19 x  19 x 512
 112 max               13x13/ 1     19 x  19 x 512 ->   19 x  19 x 512 0.031 BF
 113 route  112 110 108 107                        ->   19 x  19 x2048
 114 conv    512       1 x 1/ 1     19 x  19 x2048 ->   19 x  19 x 512 0.757 BF
 115 conv   1024       3 x 3/ 1     19 x  19 x 512 ->   19 x  19 x1024 3.407 BF
 116 conv    512       1 x 1/ 1     19 x  19 x1024 ->   19 x  19 x 512 0.379 BF
 117 conv    256       1 x 1/ 1     19 x  19 x 512 ->   19 x  19 x 256 0.095 BF
 118 upsample                 2x    19 x  19 x 256 ->   38 x  38 x 256
 119 route  85                                     ->   38 x  38 x 512
 120 conv    256       1 x 1/ 1     38 x  38 x 512 ->   38 x  38 x 256 0.379 BF
 121 route  120 118                                ->   38 x  38 x 512
 122 conv    256       1 x 1/ 1     38 x  38 x 512 ->   38 x  38 x 256 0.379 BF
 123 conv    512       3 x 3/ 1     38 x  38 x 256 ->   38 x  38 x 512 3.407 BF
 124 conv    256       1 x 1/ 1     38 x  38 x 512 ->   38 x  38 x 256 0.379 BF
 125 conv    512       3 x 3/ 1     38 x  38 x 256 ->   38 x  38 x 512 3.407 BF
 126 conv    256       1 x 1/ 1     38 x  38 x 512 ->   38 x  38 x 256 0.379 BF
 127 conv    128       1 x 1/ 1     38 x  38 x 256 ->   38 x  38 x 128 0.095 BF
 128 upsample                 2x    38 x  38 x 128 ->   76 x  76 x 128
 129 route  54                                     ->   76 x  76 x 256
 130 conv    128       1 x 1/ 1     76 x  76 x 256 ->   76 x  76 x 128 0.379 BF
 131 route  130 128                                ->   76 x  76 x 256
 132 conv    128       1 x 1/ 1     76 x  76 x 256 ->   76 x  76 x 128 0.379 BF
 133 conv    256       3 x 3/ 1     76 x  76 x 128 ->   76 x  76 x 256 3.407 BF
 134 conv    128       1 x 1/ 1     76 x  76 x 256 ->   76 x  76 x 128 0.379 BF
 135 conv    256       3 x 3/ 1     76 x  76 x 128 ->   76 x  76 x 256 3.407 BF
 136 conv    128       1 x 1/ 1     76 x  76 x 256 ->   76 x  76 x 128 0.379 BF
 137 conv    256       3 x 3/ 1     76 x  76 x 128 ->   76 x  76 x 256 3.407 BF
 138 conv    255       1 x 1/ 1     76 x  76 x 256 ->   76 x  76 x 255 0.754 BF
 139 yolo
[yolo] params: iou loss: ciou (4), iou_norm: 0.07, obj_norm: 1.00, cls_norm: 1.00, delta_norm: 1.00, scale_x_y: 1.20
nms_kind: greedynms (1), beta = 0.600000
 140 route  136                                            ->   76 x  76 x 128
 141 conv    256       3 x 3/ 2     76 x  76 x 128 ->   38 x  38 x 256 0.852 BF
 142 route  141 126                                ->   38 x  38 x 512
 143 conv    256       1 x 1/ 1     38 x  38 x 512 ->   38 x  38 x 256 0.379 BF
 144 conv    512       3 x 3/ 1     38 x  38 x 256 ->   38 x  38 x 512 3.407 BF
 145 conv    256       1 x 1/ 1     38 x  38 x 512 ->   38 x  38 x 256 0.379 BF
 146 conv    512       3 x 3/ 1     38 x  38 x 256 ->   38 x  38 x 512 3.407 BF
 147 conv    256       1 x 1/ 1     38 x  38 x 512 ->   38 x  38 x 256 0.379 BF
 148 conv    512       3 x 3/ 1     38 x  38 x 256 ->   38 x  38 x 512 3.407 BF
 149 conv    255       1 x 1/ 1     38 x  38 x 512 ->   38 x  38 x 255 0.377 BF
 150 yolo
[yolo] params: iou loss: ciou (4), iou_norm: 0.07, obj_norm: 1.00, cls_norm: 1.00, delta_norm: 1.00, scale_x_y: 1.10
nms_kind: greedynms (1), beta = 0.600000
 151 route  147                                            ->   38 x  38 x 256
 152 conv    512       3 x 3/ 2     38 x  38 x 256 ->   19 x  19 x 512 0.852 BF
 153 route  152 116                                ->   19 x  19 x1024
 154 conv    512       1 x 1/ 1     19 x  19 x1024 ->   19 x  19 x 512 0.379 BF
 155 conv   1024       3 x 3/ 1     19 x  19 x 512 ->   19 x  19 x1024 3.407 BF
 156 conv    512       1 x 1/ 1     19 x  19 x1024 ->   19 x  19 x 512 0.379 BF
 157 conv   1024       3 x 3/ 1     19 x  19 x 512 ->   19 x  19 x1024 3.407 BF
 158 conv    512       1 x 1/ 1     19 x  19 x1024 ->   19 x  19 x 512 0.379 BF
 159 conv   1024       3 x 3/ 1     19 x  19 x 512 ->   19 x  19 x1024 3.407 BF
 160 conv    255       1 x 1/ 1     19 x  19 x1024 ->   19 x  19 x 255 0.189 BF
 161 yolo
[yolo] params: iou loss: ciou (4), iou_norm: 0.07, obj_norm: 1.00, cls_norm: 1.00, delta_norm: 1.00, scale_x_y: 1.05
nms_kind: greedynms (1), beta = 0.600000
Total BFLOPS 128.459
avg_outputs = 1068395
 Allocate additional workspace_size = 35.53 MB
 Try to load weights: build/darknet/x64/yolov4.weights
Loading weights from build/darknet/x64/yolov4.weights...
 seen 64, trained: 32032 K-images (500 Kilo-batches_64)
Done! Loaded 162 layers from weights-file
Loaded - names_list: data/coco.names, classes = 80
```

After that, the image window opens and automatically closes. I don't understand what is wrong here and hopefully you could help me. If I use this command: **darknet.exe detector test cfg/coco.data cfg/yolov4.cfg yolov4.weights** in the cmd and then enter the image path: data/person.jpg, it works fine and the output is the same as the above one plus:

```
Done! Loaded 162 layers from weights-file
Enter Image Path: data/person.jpg
 Detection layer: 139 - type = 28
 Detection layer: 150 - type = 28
 Detection layer: 161 - type = 28
data/person.jpg: Predicted in 56.020000 milli-seconds.
dog: 99%
person: 100%
horse: 98%
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use OpenCV's `imshow()`, it needs to be followed with a call to `waitKey()`.  The HighGUI's event loop wont run until `waitKey()` is called.

In your case, the process gets to the end, meaning the programme ends, and so the window you create is immediately destroyed.

You should have a look at `darknet_images.py` and `darknet_video.py` in the darknet repo.